# Get xy coordinates of QgsMapCanvas in PyQGIS 3?

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqt, python-3, pyqt5

I am trying to get the `QgsMapCanvas` coordinates when they change using `PyQt5` and PyQGIS 3. What I have used for that:

```
self.canvas.scaleChanged.connect(lambda: self.showScale(self.canvas.scale()))
self.canvas.xyCoordinates.connect(lambda: self.showXY(self.canvas.xyCoordinates()))
```

and functions definitions are

```
def showXY(self, p):
    # SLOT. Show coordinates 
    self.lblXY.setText(str(p.x()) + " | " + str(p.y()))

def showScale(self, scale):
    # SLOT. Show scale 
    self.lblScale.setText("Scale 1:" + str(scale))
```

I am able to get the scale but when the `xyCoordiantes` is connected to the slot, window goes unresponsive and force closes.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to define `lambda` function and to specify `self.canvas.scale()` and `self.canvas.xyCoordinates()`. Because `scaleChanged` event passes scale and `xyCoordinates` passes coordinates to the related functions you define, by default. Thus, try in that way:

```
self.canvas.scaleChanged.connect(self.showScale)
self.canvas.xyCoordinates.connect(self.showXY)
```

**Edit**: You sometimes need to pass additional parameters to the method. In this case, use a `lambda` function.