# Getting position of point in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-python-console

How to get position of QgsPoint objects in pyqgis/ python console using QGIS 3.x?

For example:
1 points in vector layer TEST_P

```
migeometria = f.geometry()
posicion=geom.asPoint()
print(posicion.x())
```

I need current coordinate x, y

Also

Get coordinate the mouse position in map from python console.
In status bar show:

**Coordinate**: |____________|

See: line number 1084 in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/plugins/georeferencer/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp
`mCoordsLabel->setToolTip( tr( "Current map coordinate" ) );`

Comment: What have you tried?  For coding questions please always provide a code attempt.

Comment: Look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298540/get-xy-coordinates-of-qgsmapcanvas-in-pyqgis-3 It should help if I understand the question well. Standalone script to run https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/e9e3d4541836de6f608d7a02b3dde7ae

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#active layer is a point layer:
feat = next(iface.activeLayer().getFeatures())#get first feature
geo= QgsGeometry.asPoint(feat.geometry())#get the geometry of the feature
pxy=QgsPointXY(geo)
print (pxy.x(),pxy.y())
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this from console, click anywhere onto the map.
To deactivate it, click another tool eg Pan

```
class MapTool(QgsMapTool):
    def __init__(self, iface, canvas):
        super(MapTool, self).__init__(canvas)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(event.pos())
        print (point.x(),"/",point.y())

tool=MapTool(iface, iface.mapCanvas())
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```